# Image map extensions?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image, products-management

I have been searching for a long time now and can't find it by myself. I may be searching for the wrong words.

What I want is a Magento extension (or another way) to make image maps just like you can see on the H&M website. Check here the example:

http://www.hm.com/se/summer-soul --> Roll your mouse over the model and click on a random product.

I want exact that on my Magento website. How can I do it?

I have found this [plug in](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auguria-interactive-image.html) which is what I do not want! I don't want image maps on products but on static images.